# Get different input value in different places of my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input tag:

```
<input id="data-value" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a number" size="20" value="">
```

I try to get the input value, but I get different value in different places.

```
function listenForClicks(simpleStorage) {
    var button = document.querySelector('button.set')

    // (1)
    var value = document.getElementById('data-value').value

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {

        // (2)
        var value = document.getElementById('data-value').value
        ...
    }
}
```

At (1), I get "".

At (2), I get the input value.

I want to know what the reason causes this difference.

Comment: I think you have to provide more to your code example. When is listenForClicks called? From this code i speculate that the value of input actually is empty when listenForClicks is called (1). But when you later click your "button.set" button, you have populated the input with text (2)

Comment: While initialisation value is "", but later on click event is has been changed. Try to trace the order of execution with debugger and catch the value change order in whole your process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `listenForClicks` before you enter the value, you will get the `value` defined in the `input`.

In `listenForClicks` you bind `click` function to a `button` where you get the `value` when you clicked on the `button` at any time (most probably after you enter / modify the value).

```js
function listenForClicks(simpleStorage) {
    var button = document.querySelector('button.set');

    // (1)
    var value = document.getElementById('data-value').value;
    console.log(value);
    
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {

        // (2)
        var value = document.getElementById('data-value').value;
        console.log(value);
    } );
}

listenForClicks();
```

```html
<input id="data-value" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a number" size="20" value="default">
<button class="set">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer.